# How to Read SMS/MMS in UIQ

Tags: symbian, uiq3, uiq

How to Read SMS/MMS in UIQ ?

Answer (score 3):

I am going to assume that you want information about how to write some C++ source code that will allow an application to receive SMS/MMS and read the content of the messages it receives.

---

On Symbian OS, the message store can store SMS, MMS, EMAIL...

The API of the message store is generic.

In order to write and read data to/from the message store, you'll need to familiarise yourself with the following classes : TMsvId, CMsvSession, CClientMtmRegistry, TMsvEntry and CMsvEntry.

---

I am obviously biased but I would advise reading the messaging chapter of http://www.quickrecipesonsymbianos.com in order to get an explanation of how the messaging store works and the sample code to use it easily.

---

Receiving messages, on the other hand, is more complicated.

---

Listening for and receiving SMS is done using the generic networking API. That's RSocketServ and RSocket. Mostly, you need to use to the right IOCTL parameters on the socket.

You can specify a specific port in order to only receive SMS that are intended for your application. Trying to receive all SMS could be an issue as the native message viewer engine and the embedded Java virtual machine PushRegistry module could both be listening for all SMS already.

You will find useful classes and constants in the following header files in your SDK:
gsmuset.h smsuaddr.h smsustrm.h gsmubuf.h gsmumsg.h.

TSmsAddr, KSMSDatagramProtocol, KSMSAddrFamily, TSmsUserDataSettings, CSmsBufferBase, CSmsPDU, RSmsSocketReadStream, RSmsSocketWriteStream and CSmsMessage are of particular interest. Asynchronously receiving an SMS is actually done using RSocket.Ioctl().

There are SMS-specific error codes whose names start with "KSmsErr"

---

Receiving MMS on UIQ is done through a UQI-specific API. One that you won't find on Series60 phones. This is the reason why you won't find much talk of a Symbian-generic MMS API in the litterature. You are better off going directly to the UIQ or Sony-Ericsson development communities when you have more detailled questions.

Your application shouldn't have to use RSocket to receive MMS.

Careful, once again, both the Embedded Java virtual machine PushRegistry module and the native message viewer application engine are probably already listening for all incoming MMS messages.

The interesting header files are mmsclient.h, MmsSettingsStore.h, mmsentry.h, MmsApiExtensions.h

Of particular interest are CMmsClientMtm, MmsApiExtensions, MMsvSessionObserver and MMMSMessageHandler.

---

Good luck.